# Equation of a helix parametrized by arc length between two points in space

Tags: math, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

What is the equation of a helix **parametrized by arc length** (i.e. a function of arc length) between any two points in space? Is there any function for this ? How do i implement the same using matlab or mathematica ?

Comment: No sir,it is for implementing in my project.

Comment: It is a small module and i am breaking my head regarding its implementation.

Answer (score 3):

just to add to Mitch Wheat's answer, helices are not unique; for a given axis, the degrees of freedom are distance between turns, radius, and phase (`P`, `A`, and  `phi` below)

if you generalize to

```
w = 2*pi/P
r(t) = (A cos (wt-phi)) i + (A sin (wt-phi)) j + (t) k
```

then one way to analyze the arclength as a function of t (without having to compute the arclength integral explicitly) is to realize that the magnitude of velocity is constant; the component of velocity parallel to the radius is 0, the component of velocity parallel to the axis is `1`, the component of velocity perpendicular to both radius and axis is `Aw`, so therefore the magnitude of velocity is speed = sqrt(1 + A<sup>2</sup>w<sup>2</sup>), => arclength s = sqrt(1 + A<sup>2</sup>w<sup>2</sup>)t

You'd need some way of defining the axis, `P`, `A` and `phi` as a function of whatever inputs you are given. Just the endpoints and arclength wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 2):

To find the arc length parameterization of the helix defined by

```
    r(t)  =  cos t i + sin t j + t k
```

Arc Length = s = Integral(a,b){sqrt((dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2 + (dz/dt)^2) dt}

First find the arc length function

```
     s(t) = Integral(0,t) { sqrt((sin u)^2 + (cos u)^2 + 1) du }
          = Integral(0,t) { sqrt(2) du } = sqrt(2) * t
```

Solving for t gives

```
    t   =  s / sqrt(2)
```

Now substitute back to get

```
    r(s)  =  cos(s / sqrt(2)) i + sin(s / sqrt(2)) j + (s / sqrt(2)) k
```

I'll leave the last bit to you!

Comment: When are we going to get some of that sexy equation formatting loving they get on the stackexchange math site? Great answers like this would be so much more legible!