# Arc length parametrization using R

Tags: r

I am dealing with 2-dimensional parametric curve f.

Is there there is any function in R (in any package) which gives the arc-length parametrization for any such given parametric f?

I know how to derive the arc-length parametrized function from a given function. It involves derivative and integration as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556601/equation-of-a-helix-parametrized-by-arc-length-between-two-points-in-space). But looking for whether there is any R function for computation of arc-length parametrization.

Answer (score 2):

The [pracma package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/) seems to have the functions you are looking for.  See `arclength()` in particular on page 23 of the [pracma documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf).

Comment: Arclength() gives only value of the arclength of a given curve. Here I am looking for another curve which is parametried by arclength.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood.  Are you looking for an  R function that will return the derived arc-length parametrization function with the values specific to the provided curve substituted into the equation?  If so, I don't believe there is any function for that.

Comment: Yes I am looking for such function in R. Thanks for attention.

Comment: But it is a few lines of code to generate such an arc-length parametrization by utilizing the `arclength` function. There will be an example of how to do that on the help page of `arclength` in the next version.
(The margin of a comment is not large enough to write it down completely.)